# Как удалить конкретный элемент из строки?

Tags: javascript, строки

В массивах для этого есть splice. Есть ли функция которая делает то же самое, только со строкой?

Comment: slice, substr, substring

Comment: В массивах нет split ;)

Comment: имелось в виду splice, уже исправил

Comment: Почему в массивах нет split ?

Comment: slice/substr/substring мне не подходят, тк требуется удалить конкретный символ, а не вернуть его как новую строку

Comment: Примитивная строка не является объектом, в отличие от массива. [Примитивы неизменны](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive).

Comment: @Leks, потому что он в строках :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот, примерчики тебе, я почти всегда использую `.split.join` конструкцию, она не сильно проигрывает по производительности и полностью меня удовлетворяет

```js
const test1=(str)=>{
    str = str.replace(' big', '');
    console.log(str); // only first 'big' removed
};

const test2=(str)=>{
    str = str.split(' big').join('');
    console.log(str); // all 'big'
};

let str = 'My big string lol, big big';

test1(str);
test2(str);

// or:
let arr = str.split(' ');
// you can use splice now
console.log(arr);
```

Я думаю после `.split` для тебя откроется решение которое ты ищешь, если эти `test1\2` не подходят, удачки